# Making a child components element fixed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to be able to make a breadcrumb element fixed on the top of the child components page.

[image: how to]

my layout is here:

```
const style = {
  container: `h-screen overflow-hidden relative`,
  mainContainer: `bg-gray-800 flex flex-col h-screen pl-0 w-full]`,
  main: `bg-gray-400 h-screen overflow-auto pb-36  md:pb-8  lg:rounded-tl-3xl`,
};

export default function DefaultLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <DashboardProvider>
      <div className={style.container}>
        <div className="flex items-start">
          <Overlay />
          <SideNavigation mobilePosition="left" />
          <div className={style.mainContainer}>
            <TopNavigation />
            <main className={style.main}>{children}</main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </DefaultProvider>
  );
}
```

each page on the application is inside this area under the header and to the right of the side navigation.

I want to be able to have a fixed breadcrumb element on top of my child component (the top of the inner child component, which is below the overall navigation header):

```
const ItemDetail = (props: ItemDetailProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex-1 flex items-stretch overflow-hidden">
      <main className="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
        <nav
          className="bg-white border-b border-gray-200 flex"
          aria-label="Breadcrumb"
        >
          <ol
            role="list"
            className="max-w-screen-xl w-full mx-auto px-4 flex space-x-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8"
          >
            <li className="flex">
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <a href="#" className="text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
                  <HomeIcon
                    className="flex-shrink-0 h-5 w-5"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  />
                  <span className="sr-only">Home</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
            {pages.map((page) => (
              <li key={page.name} className="flex">
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <svg
                    className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-full text-gray-200"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 44"
                    preserveAspectRatio="none"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path d="M.293 0l22 22-22 22h1.414l22-22-22-22H.293z" />
                  </svg>
                  <a
                    href={page.href}
                    className="ml-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700"
                    aria-current={page.current ? "page" : undefined}
                  >
                    {page.name}
                  </a>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ol>
        </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

The issue is that I cannot make it fixed. I think it's because a child component.
I want it fixed so when I scroll down on the child component the breadcrumb will stay on top.

I know the height of the header navigation strip, so I also tried fixed top-20 but that did not work either.

Comment: What happens when you put position fixed? Also, did you check if position sticky helps?

Comment: Yeah tried both. When I do fixed it makes the breadcrumbs part vanish.