# tailwind h-screen container is (header amount of height) too far off the bottom of the screen

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a layout that has the left navigation, the top navigation bar and then the main area for the child components. The issue is all the child components slightly push down past the bottom of the screen.

I can somewhat fix this by adding a pb-36 for example but that leaves an annoying gap.

```
const style = {
  container: `h-screen overflow-hidden relative `,
  mainContainer: `bg-gray-800 flex flex-col  pl-0   w-full lg:w-[calc(100%-13rem)]`,
  main: `bg-gray-100  h-screen overflow-auto lg:rounded-tl-3xl `,
};
```

the rendered part:

```
 <LayoutProvider>
      <div className={style.container}>
        <div className="flex items-start">
          <Overlay />
          <SideNavigation mobilePosition="left" />
          <div className={style.mainContainer}>
            <TopNavigation />
            <main className={style.main}>{children}</main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </LayoutProvider>
```

For example, if I remove the TopNavigation above, then it will remove the header and then the child components will fit correctly. So the child components are offset down by that much.

[image: des]

top navigation is :

```
 <header className="bg-gray-800 h-[74px] items-center relative w-full ">
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Since the header is occupying `74px` of the screen, you have to reduce the height of the child component by the height of the header. So replace the main's `h-screen` with `h-[calc(100vh-74px)]`

I mean change

```
main: `bg-gray-100  h-screen overflow-auto lg:rounded-tl-3xl `
```

To this instead

```
main: `bg-gray-100  h-[calc(100vh-74px)] overflow-auto lg:rounded-tl-3xl `
```

Comment: thanks, perhaps you would also know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672706/making-a-child-components-element-fixed

Comment: Have this heart sir <3

Answer (score 1):

if you are using tailwindcss then just add `min-h-[calc(100vh-63px)]` into your parent html tag, make sure your child element don't have the same property there.
just only add it into the parent tag.

replace `63px` with your header height.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).